# How can I prevent this code to optimize my game from recurring in each scene?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the graphics of a game that I'm creating in Unity and I found this code that improves my FPS, but I do not know why every time it changes the scene it is executed again. I have tried with DontDestroyOnLoad... creating a Boolean so that this part could be executed only once... but nothing.

The code is this:

```
[SerializeField]
float factor = 0.5f;

    void Start ()
    {   
      Screen.SetResolution(
      Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.currentResolution.width * factor),
      Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.currentResolution.height * factor), true);
    }
```

What I can be doing wrong?
Thanks greetings.

Comment: Does this script exist on an object in every scene? if so that is why it is executing in every scene...  I would suggest placing this on 1 object in 1 scene that will ever be loaded once (Like a splash screen)  then make sure it doesn't exist on any other object.

Comment: I tried putting it in an empty object and DontDestroyOnLoad so it would not run anymore, but in the game every time I change the scene it loses half the quality. I have also tried creating a Boolean so that the code will be executed only once but it happens the same. (I feel my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about `DontDestroyOnLoad` is: Anyway if you load the same scene again (or any other scene which contains that component) it will be run again if you don't combine it with a "singleton"-pattern for making sure there exists always only one of that component.

---

But In your case you could instead simply use a `static bool` (static values are saved for the whole execution of the app)

```
[SerializeField] private float factor = 0.5f;

private static bool alreadySetResolution;

private void Start()
{   
    if(!alreadySetResolution) SetResolution();
}

private void SetResolution()
{
    Screen.SetResolution(
        Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.currentResolution.width * factor),
        Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.currentResolution.height * factor), 
        true
    );

    alreadySetResolution = true;
}
```